# Words To Replace "Said" When Annoyed

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm looking for words that can replace "said" when a person is annoyed.

Say someone was trying to write, for example:

*He waved his hand in front of their face, startling them. "Hello-o-o," he **said**. "I'm right here."*

Something is needed to replace said to show the boy is exasperated.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This is more of a writing advice kind of question, I believe.

Comment: Generally, we use an alternative that is descriptive of the way it's said, like *barked at*, *roared*, *howled*, so on.

Comment: What's wrong with saying "... he said (,) annoyed / exasperated..."?

Comment: 'I'm fed up with this!' he **snapped**

Comment: There are a lot of possible words. Which one you use depends to a large extent on the particular attitude and emotion displayed by the boy. At one extreme *thundered* or *roared* might do the trick. At another it could be *pleaded*, or *whispered*.

Comment: How about miffed?

Comment: I realize this is an old, closed question but..... [**quipped**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/quipped)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a thesaurus: [Oxford Dictionaries Thesaurus](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/)
You wont find anything useful if you just type in "said", but you can try several different things like "yelled", "shouted", or "exclaimed". You're looking for a synonym that matches the emotional level of annoyance.